# Find three whole numbers with these characteristics

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find three whole numbers with the sum 147, knowing that the quotient of the second and first is 2 and the remainder 3 and the quotient of the third with the second is 3 and the remainder 2. Here's what i did:
a+b+c=147
b=2a+3
c=3b+2
I put the in system::
$$-2a+b=3$$
$$-3b+c=2$$
$$a+b+c=147$$
[image: Click here to watch my solution]

a is not a whole number. Could you tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Division algebras does not mean what you think it means...

Comment: I tried it with $\begin{cases}b=2a + 3 \\ c=3b+2\end{cases}$ and with $\begin{cases}a=2b + 3 \\ b=3c+2\end{cases}$ and both ways the solutions are not whole numbers.  Either there's a typo here or your professor/ book made a mistake.